# rewriting sql user-defined function into a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Good day.. I've been stressing out for a week now on how to rewriting this sql user-defined function into a stored procedure utilizing a temporary table...and also to speed up the query process...  to be honest I think its overwhelming for my level of sql knowledge and I would gladly appreciate if you could help... at least to have a reference on the other sql statements I would be working on...

```
CREATE FUNCTION SALES  
(  

@SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
@BATCHID VARCHAR(50)  
)  
RETURNS  

@STOCKDETAILS TABLE  
(  

 [ID] CHAR(1),  
 [BATCH RECEIVEDATE] DATETIME,  
 SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
 [NOW - RECEVEDATE] INT,  
 [DUEDATE] VARCHAR(50)  
)  
AS  
BEGIN  

DECLARE @RECEIVEDATE DATETIME,  
  @SUPPLIERCODE1 VARCHAR(15)  

 SELECT TOP 1  
  @RECEIVEDATE = O.ReceivedDate,  
  @SUPPLIERCODE1 = A.SUPPLIERCODE  
 FROM TRANSACT.dbo.FIELDS A WITH(NOLOCK)  
 INNER JOIN TRANSACT.dbo.DELIV O WITH(NOLOCK) ON O.BATCHID = A.BATCHID  


 DECLARE @ID1 TABLE(SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(50))  
 INSERT INTO @ID1  
 SELECT P.SUPPLIERCODE  
 FROM  
 (  
  SELECT  
   [SUPPLIERCODE] = SUPPLIERCODE,  
   [TOTAL] = ISNULL(SUM(ITEMPRICE+(ITEMPRICE*.12)),0)  
  FROM TRANSACT.dbo.ProviderDiscount WITH(NOLOCK)  
  WHERE ACQUIREDDATE <> '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'  
   AND SUPPLIERCODE = @SUPPLIERCODE1  
  GROUP BY SUPPLIERCODE  
 ) P  
 WHERE P.TOTAL <> 0  


 DECLARE @ID TABLE(  
  [BATCH RECEIVEDATE] DATETIME,  
  SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
  ACQUIREDDATE DATETIME,  
  Coverage VARCHAR(20),  
  CoverageItem VARCHAR(10),  
  [NOW - RECEVEDATE] INT,  
  DiscTerm1 INT,DiscTerm2 INT,DiscTerm3 INT,DiscTerm4 INT,DiscTerm5 INT,  
  [NEW ACQUIREDDATE] VARCHAR(50)  
 )  
 INSERT INTO @ID  
 SELECT DISTINCT  
  [BATCH RECEIVEDATE] = @RECEIVEDATE,  
  B.SUPPLIERCODE,  
  B.ACQUIREDDATE,  
  B.Coverage,  
  B.CoverageItem,  
  [NOW - RECEVEDATE] = DATEDIFF(DAY,@RECEIVEDATE,GETDATE()),  
  B.DiscTerm1,B.DiscTerm2,B.DiscTerm3,B.DiscTerm4,B.DiscTerm5,  
  [NEW ACQUIREDDATE] =  
   TRANSACT.dbo.fxnGetIDNewACQUIREDDATE(  
    B.DiscTerm1,  
    B.DiscTerm2,  
    B.DiscTerm3,  
    B.DiscTerm4,  
    B.DiscTerm5,  
    @RECEIVEDATE  
   )  
 FROM TRANSACT.dbo.ProviderDiscount B WITH(NOLOCK)  
 INNER JOIN  
 (  
  SELECT  
   [ACQUIREDDATE] = MAX(ACQUIREDDATE),  
   [REOD] = MAX(REOD)  
  FROM TRANSACT.dbo.ProviderDiscount B2 WITH(NOLOCK)  
  INNER JOIN @ID1 B1 ON B1.SUPPLIERCODE = B2.SUPPLIERCODE  
  WHERE B2.Coverage = @CLAIMTYPE  
   AND B2.ACQUIREDDATE < @RECEIVEDATE  
 ) B3 ON B3.REOD = B.REOD  




    INSERT INTO @STOCKDETAILS  
 SELECT DISTINCT  
  [ID] = 'Y',  
  [BATCH RECEIVEDATE],  
  SUPPLIERCODE,  
  [NOW - RECEVEDATE],  
  [DUEDATE] = MIN([NEW ACQUIREDDATE])  
 FROM @ID  
 WHERE ISNULL([NEW ACQUIREDDATE],'NONE') <> 'NONE'  
 GROUP BY [BATCH RECEIVEDATE], SUPPLIERCODE, [NOW - RECEVEDATE]  

 RETURN  
END
```

Comment: I don't understand the motivation.  Stored procedures don't necessarily perform better than user defined functions.  Why are you trying to change it?

Comment: As I've stated this would only be a reference on the future sql queries I would be working on.. I have to build my foundation in case needed... hope you could help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Your user defined function *is* using temporary tables, just in the form of table variables rather than in the form of an explicit temporary table.  I'm not sure what motivation there would be to switch from one to another.

Stored procedures are more "general" than user-defined functions.  For instance, they can call other stored procedures and execute dynamic SQL.  To convert a user-defined function to a stored procedure you can simply remove the `INSERT INTO @STOCKDETAILS` statement before the final select.

However, the user-define function is *much* more useful.  You can reference it in a query (in the `from` clause).  You can't do that with a stored procedure.  Stick with the function if you can.

EDIT:

*And* you would change the declaration to:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SALES  ( 
    @SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
    @BATCHID VARCHAR(50)  
)  
BEGIN
 . . .
```

By the way, I think it is a good idea to prefix stored procedures and functions so you can readily identify them.  I would use "usp_" and "udf_" for this purpose.

Comment: thank you very much for your though @gordon linoff ... So that would mean that the function declaration: `code`CREATE FUNCTION SALES  
(  

@SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
@BATCHID VARCHAR(50)  
)  
RETURNS  

@STOCKDETAILS TABLE  
(  

 [ID] CHAR(1),  
 [BATCH RECEIVEDATE] DATETIME,  
 SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
 [NOW - RECEVEDATE] INT,  
 [DUEDATE] VARCHAR(50)  
)  
`code` 
would just be `code`create STOCKDETAILS TABLE  
(  

 [ID] CHAR(1),  
 [BATCH RECEIVEDATE] DATETIME,  
 SUPPLIERCODE VARCHAR(15),  
 [NOW - RECEVEDATE] INT,  
 [DUEDATE] VARCHAR(50)  
)`code`

Comment: that really helped a lot... can I have one last question... now that I'm converting the function to a procedure... what would be the best advice to speed up the query process.. using indexes is a given... but is the structure of my sql query alright... or can I still alter a bit to make it more efficient..